# How i can check dual data entry in SQL/ PLSql

Tags: sql, plsql

Dual data entry checking. Same data is enterd by two persons and now i want to compare this to ensure data quality.

Comment: create a `unique` constraint

Comment: Please post sample data and what is expected. Do you need the checks at the table level or from a procedure?. Also let us know what you have tried so far if anything..

Answer (score 0):

This will depend a lot the measure of quality that you want to use.
As an example, you can just check for the fraction of entries that match exactly,

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS MatchedData
```

Then you can sum MatchedData and divide by the total number of entries

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery for this. First you need to decide which are columns when two records have the identical value in are considered duplicate records. Like you said the records entered by different users so they may have created_by_user column (if exists) different value and all other same. then put them in below sub query below to get the list of duplicate records.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
MY_TABLE t1
WHERE
ROWID <> (
    SELECT
        MAX(ROWID)
    FROM
        MY_TABLE t2
    WHERE
            t1.col1 = t2.col1
        AND
            t1.col2 = t2.col2
)
```